# Nodejs server randomly requires user input on console line to run

Tags: node.js, web, server, client, webserver

So I'm working on a web server to host a website to talk to a teradata database, but every now and then when I send a request from the website back to the server, it will do nothing until I focus the console and press any key. Does anyone know why this is and how I can fix it?

I'm using XMLHttpRequests on the website and using the default Nodejs http package on the server side. Let me know if you need more information about it that I haven't included here.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out this was an issue with CMD/Powershell select mode.